# Question regarding Particular Integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was reading Particular Integral.

Following is done in my book. I can not understand how the third line came from second line.

$\frac{1}{D^2+a^2} \sin  ax = \frac{1}{D^2+a^2}(\text{imaginary part of } \cos ax + \iota \sin ax) = \text{imaginary part of } (\frac{1}{D^2+a^2} \cos ax + \iota \frac{1}{D^2+a^2} \sin ax ) $

Here $D$ is $\frac{d}{dx}$.

Can anyone please help me to understand ?

Comment: It comes from the definition of $\frac 1 {D^{2}+a^{2}} (f+ig)=\frac 1 {D^{2}+a^{2}} f+i\frac 1 {D^{2}+a^{2}} g$ for real valued $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it little bit ?@KaviRamaMurthy